# quickbooks integration in rails application (parameter rejected OAuth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, quickbooks

I am creating a rails application to post invoices to quickbooks I am using this gem `quickbooks-ruby` every time when I try to authenticate with quickbooks It gives this error `OAuth::Problem parameter_rejected` below is my code.

**quickbook.rb (initialiser)**

```
    ::QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER = OAuth::Consumer.new(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, {
    :site                 => "https://oauth.intuit.com",
    :request_token_path   => "/oauth/v1/get_request_token",
    :authorize_url        => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin",
    :access_token_path    => "/oauth/v1/get_access_token"
})
```

**Authenticate method in controller**

```
 def authenticate_quickbooks    
    callback = api_webhooks_quickbook_oauth_callback_path
    token = QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => callback)
    session[:qb_request_token] = token
    redirect_to("https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin?oauth_token=#{token.token}") and return

  end
```

**callback**

```
def quickbooks_oauth_callback
    at = session[:qb_request_token].get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
    token = at.token
    secret = at.secret
    realm_id = params['realmId']
  end
```

Comment: You may want to see this issue https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/issues/395

Comment: There's also a quickbooks-ruby branch aimed at supporting Oauth 2.0: https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/tree/389-oauth2

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved. My quickbooks app was using oAuth2 and the gem has different method of authentication for oAuth1 and oAuth2. 
below is the code **(for OAuth2)**:

**quickbook.rb (initialiser)**

```
oauth_params = {
  :site => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
  :authorize_url => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
  :token_url => "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer"
}

::QB_OAUTH2_CONSUMER = OAuth2::Client.new(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, oauth_params)
Quickbooks.sandbox_mode = true
```

**Authenticate method in controller**

```
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000#{quickbooks_authenticate_callback_path}"
      grant_url = ::QB_OAUTH2_CONSUMER.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => redirect_uri, :response_type => "code", :state => SecureRandom.hex(12), :scope => "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting")
      redirect_to grant_url
```

**callback**

```
 redirect_uri = oauth_callback_quickbooks_url
      if resp = ::QB_OAUTH2_CONSUMER.auth_code.get_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => redirect_uri)
```

where `oauth_callback_quickbooks_url = application callback which is also defined in quickbooks app`
please note that you also have to include `oauth2` gem

Comment: I am trying to integrate quickbook. but I'm getting an redirect_uri error in authenticate method. what url shall I specify in redirect_uri hash after localhost. (in your case from where did you get this path 'quickbooks_authenticate_callback_path')

Comment: just define callback method in the controller and create a named path in the routes file should work